# SSJS Debug in Xpages Not Firing

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have set up SSJS debugging on our test server. About 2 months ago I was able to use it successfully.

No I am trying to debug on a different design element. I am able to connect to the server, and get to the debug view.

But I cannot get the debugger to fire.

I put a button on a form with SSJS in the Execute Script action. Put a debug statement in there, set a var, and call a function, like so:

```
debugger;
var xxx = 1;
computeApprovers()
```

Then open the page form designer and hit the button; can see that the function computeApprovers gets fired because I put a print statement in there, BUT I am never thrown into the debugger.

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You did set breakpoint in Designer, didn't you? http://www.notesin9.com/2013/04/05/notesin9-105-introduction-to-ssjs-debugger

Comment: Yes. I believe I found my problem. I was opening the design in XPiNC not on the web. Once on the web, the debugger fired. I wish we could debug in the client.